# Put every values between two TRUE into a new Group

Tags: r

My vector is:

```
vec <- c(T,rep(F,4),T,rep(F,8),T,F,F,T)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

I want to group the vector from TRUE to TRUE.

#### Desired result:

```
grp <- c(rep(1,5),rep(2,9),3,3,3,4)
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

#### My Try:

```
rleidv(vec) + vec
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 8
```

This is okay but not sure whether this works all the time

Comment: It is just `grp <- cumsum(vec)` you are looking for

Comment: True that! Nice and simple